# How to change axis properties for the imagesc function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I plotted a 2-D map using imagesc. The x axis should range from -1000 to 1000 "left to right" and Y axis should range from -1000 to a 1000 "bottom to top". When I use imagesc function, the y axis ranges from 1000 to -1000 "bottom to top" which is opposite what I want.any idea of how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MATLAB help:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)

> By default, imagesc plots the y-axis from lowest to highest value, top to bottom. To reverse this, type `set(gca,'YDir','normal')`. This will reverse both the y-axis and the image.

You can also use `axis xy` which does something similar (the default is `axis ij` which puts the lowest index on top).

Comment: i tried axis xy but it flips the image. I want to keep the image.

Comment: try `imagesc(x, y(end:-1:1), img); axis xy`, that should do what you want.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem (apparently it did) @mohamed. Thanks!